# xmlhttp.responseText not display text

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

I'm having a situation with ajax responseText. The response text from url is well function. But something inside the ajax code goes wrong. It doesn't recognize the response text and add class to the targeted id. Here's the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateField(nameValue){
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try{
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
catch (e){
    try{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
catch (e){
    alert("No AJAX!");
    return false;
    }
}
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if (xmlHttp.status==200){
            //this will be called after update
                var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;        
            }
        }
    }
    //this will send the data to server to be updated
    xmlHttp.open("GET", 'inc/room_rate_updatez.php?'+ nameValue, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function doSomethingAfterUpdate(retValFromPHP){
//retValFromPHP can be any thing you want!

    if (reponseText == "Failed"){
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.className = "error";
    }else{
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.className = "success";
    }
}

</script>

<div id="result"></div><input type="text" name="rate|498|6500-5200-4600-5600-4100|0" id="498" value="6500" size="10" onchange="updateField(this.name + '=' + this.value);"/>
```

The response from room_rate_updatez.php are "Succeed" and "Failed".
I've tried many times to make it work but no luck. Please suggest.

Comment: Firefox (with firebug) and chrome both let you watch all network requests. What does that panel say?

Comment: @Jeremy Firebug returns "Succeed". What I suppose to do now?

Comment: how do you call doSomethingAfterUpdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateField(nameValue){
   var xmlHttp=null;
   ....
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if (xmlHttp.status==200){
            //this will be called after update
                var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;        
                doSomethingAfterUpdate(responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    //this will send the data to server to be updated
    xmlHttp.open("GET", 'inc/room_rate_updatez.php?'+ nameValue, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}



function doSomethingAfterUpdate(retValFromPHP){
//retValFromPHP can be any thing you want!

    if (retValFromPHP == "Failed"){
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "error";
       document.getElementById("result").className = "error" 
    }else{
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "success";
       document.getElementById("result").className = "success" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. Strange) It has a mistake as I took a part of code got a mess with curly brackets. Besides, `var responseTex`t - this way you create a local variable which is, in most cases - not seen from outside of a function.

Comment: one more question about this. How can I call the css class to decorate the div? For example : if innerHTML=error it calls error which result the div and text inside it red. Thanks

Comment: document.getElementById("result").className = "your_red_class_name"

Comment: Can I use innerHTML and className together?

Comment: I use this : 
`document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src=\"../images/ico_check.png\" alt=\"Y\" />".className="success";`

but the it shows "success" instead of picture and no green text of success class. Please suggest.

Comment: `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src=\"../images/ico_check.png\" alt=\"Y\" />".className="success"` that looks like jquery style of coding, but it will not work with pure JS

Comment: A new problem arise. Because I have multiple input and status box (<div id="result">). Wherever I update, it's keep updating only the first box of the table. Now the question : is it possible to get the id of the box from php and update the exact box?

Comment: sure. It is possible. How - everything is up to you. You can create some object on server side and return it with json_encode and make a JS object from string using JSON.parse in browser. Or you may just return a simple string, like now, but add div id like next: divID|success, so it is possible to split it using | and get a both values in array

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. My script is a lot progress - even the issue remains.

Comment: @Wilf Good luck with your script. As I understand you have no exprience in JS at all and looks like small experience in programming. My advice - understand basic reules of your PL first. And than think how you can solve your problem based on that understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. By the way I'm only good at HTML, CSS and some what which is shallower than these scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
Check the readyState & status like below.

if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
 {
  var httpResp=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
var scriptObj1 = $.parseJSON(httpResp);
```